# Removing Escape Sequence From C# Directory

Tags: c#, python, directory, escaping

I've written the current working directory in my C# project to a .txt file so that my python script can read it in, the issue is that the text in the .txt file contains the escape sequence characters

> ERROR Message: WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name,
>   or volume label syntax is incorrect:
>   'C:\Users\chris\Dropbox\Shared Visual Studio Projects\GitHub
>   Projects\GitHub Group Project
>   Beta\GroupProject\GroupProject\bin\Debug\Material Lists\n'

**C# Code that writes the text file:**

```
            if (DEBUGGING)
        {               
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "//ScriptInformation.txt");
            sw.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            sw.Close();
        }
```

**Python Script, Trying to change directories so I can delete certain files:**

```
import os
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

myfile = open(filename)
newdir = myfile.readline()
os.chdir(newdir)
myfile.close()
print os.getcwd()
```

EDIT: Just rechecked the .txt file and the actual text says:

> C:\Users\chris\Dropbox\Shared Visual Studio Projects\GitHub
>   Projects\GitHub Group Project
>   Beta\GroupProject\GroupProject\bin\Debug\Material Lists

Comment: How did you write the file? Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the "\n". Just used the `.rstrip()` method to cut it in my python script. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[TextWriter.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt(v=vs.110).aspx) writes a string followed by a line terminator.
Use [TextWriter.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay30k2f(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

And using [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) is much easier:

```
File.WriteAllText(txtPath, content);
```